# Subtract the value in a field in one row from all other rows of the same field in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
data = {'sid':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
        'field1':['start', None, None, 'start', None, None], 
        'field2':['a', 'b', 'z', 'd', 'z','s'],
        'val':[20, 22, 23, 40, 45, 47]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   sid field1  val
0    1  start   20
1    1   None   22
2    1   None   23
3    2  start   40
4    2   None   45
5    2   None   47
```

I would like to create a new field *newval* which stores the difference between *val* of that row and the *val* in the row with same *sid* and *field1* = 'start'.

```
   sid field1  val  newval
0    1  start   20     NaN
1    1   None   22     2.0
2    1   None   23     3.0
3    2  start   40     NaN
4    2   None   45     5.0
5    2   None   47     7.0
```

I have tried diff() with groupby() but that gives me a running difference.

```
 df['newval'] = df.groupby('sid')['val'].diff()

   sid field1  val  newval
0    1  start   20     NaN
1    1   None   22     2.0
2    1   None   23     1.0
3    2  start   40     NaN
4    2   None   45     5.0
5    2   None   47     2.0
```

How can I get the difference from a particular row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groupby with a helper column and `sid` and then get first value of the group and then subtract from `val` field.

```
df['new_val'] = (df['val']-
     df.groupby(['sid',df['field1'].eq("start").cumsum()])['val'].transform("first"))
```

---

```
print(df)

   sid field1 field2  val  new_val
0    1  start      a   20        0
1    1   None      b   22        2
2    1   None      z   23        3
3    2  start      d   40        0
4    2   None      z   45        5
5    2   None      s   47        7
```

The helper column is as below, which helps in grouping:

```
print(df['field1'].eq("start").cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: field1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: In the most general case, where there are multiple starts in each id and the data is not sorted by id, this might fail.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could do a join on just the rows with `field1 = 'start'`

Using `df` as defined above:

```
tmp = pd.merge(df, df.loc[df['field1'] == 'start', ['sid', 'val']],
        how = 'left', left_on = 'sid', right_on = 'sid',
        suffixes = ['', 'start_val'])

tmp['newval'] = np.where(tmp['field1'] == 'start', np.nan, tmp['val'] - tmp['valstart_val'])
tmp.drop('valstart_val', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
sid field1  field2  val newval
1   start   a   20  NaN
1   None    b   22  2.0
1   None    z   23  3.0
2   start   d   40  NaN
2   None    z   45  5.0
2   None    s   47  7.0
```

Comment: I like anky's solution

Comment: As an FYI, there is [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values), which removes a need to import `numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your data is already sorted by `sid` and there is only one `start` at the first row of each Id. In which case, you can do:

```
ids = df.duplicated(['sid'])
# also
# ids = df['field1'].astype(bool)

df['newval'] = df['val'].sub(df['val'].mask(ids).ffill()).where(ids)
```

Output:

```
   sid field1 field2  val  newval
0    1  start      a   20     NaN
1    1   None      b   22     2.0
2    1   None      z   23     3.0
3    2  start      d   40     NaN
4    2   None      z   45     5.0
5    2   None      s   47     7.0
```